# Elasticsearch combine 2 filter context queries with OR

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query, it correctly finds documents that have a NAME field but do NOT have  a NEW_NAME field:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "filter": {
      "exists": {
        "field": "NAME"
      }
    },
    "must_not": {
      "exists": {
        "field": "NEW_NAME"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to extend this query (by OR'ing it) with another query so that it also finds documents that have a DOB field but do NOT have a NEW_DOB field, e.g.

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "filter": {
      "exists": {
        "field": "DOB"
      }
    },
    "must_not": {
      "exists": {
        "field": "NEW_DOB"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so my query is something like:

```
(NAME exists AND NEW_NAME !exist) OR (DOB exists AND NEW_DOB !exist)
```

I think I need to combine the above two queries using should, just not sure exactly how, this does not work:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "NAME"
            }
          },
          "must_not": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "NEW_NAME"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "DOB"
            }
          },
          "must_not": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "NEW_DOB"
            }
          }
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "filter": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "NAME"
                  }
                },
                "must_not": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "NEW_NAME"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "filter": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "DOB"
                  }
                },
                "must_not": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "NEW_DOB"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

I just combined with must and should.

must = AND
should = OR

Comment: Thanks, does using must not mean it's using the query context and not the filter context though? Meaning documents are scored?

Comment: Must_not executed in filter context. So it doesn't contribute to the scoring.

Comment: But does the outer must contribute to scoring? I don't want documents scored, I only want to use filter context to perform these queries

Comment: You could replace `must` by `filter` in that case. Query remains the same apart from that.